# Duplicate parameters in Angular $http

Tags: javascript, angular, http

I want to add multiple parameters with the same name to a request URL. I'm using Angular's `$http`.

The URL should look like this: 
`http://myBaseUrl?name1=value1&name1=value2...`

I know that it is possible to make something like this when I set the values as an array:
`http://myBaseUrl?name1=value1,value2...`

But it has to be like the first one.

Comment: why do you need to add same key twice? GET HTTP request uses key=value structure

Comment: I know that it is not pretty. But the api expects the values this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're using [`HttpClient`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) you can use [`HttpParams`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams) for this.

```
let params = new HttpParams();

// Assign parameters
params = params.append('firstParameter', 'valueOne');
params = params.append('firstParameter', 'valueTwo');

// Get request
this.http.get(`http://example.com`, { params }).subscribe();
```

Comment: In our project this is broken after upgrade from Angular 7 to Angular 15. Still searching a solution.